# Interface in method signature inside interface definition

Tags: go, interface

I want to have something like this:

```
type MyInterface interface {
    MyMetod(interface{})
}
```

and to have the type

```
type MyType struct {}
```

with method

```
func (mt *MyType) MyMethod(SomeConcreteType) {
   // body
}
```

implementing **MyInterface**.

But it seems that Go can't handle this. I recieve an error that says that it have **MyMethod(SomeConcreteType)** but it wants **MyMethod(interface{})**. Why is this so, and what would be a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is this? It's the language design.

Solution would be to match the interface:

```
type MyType struct{}

func (mt *MyType) MyMethod(v interface{}) {
    v, ok := v.(SomeConcreteType)
    if !ok {
        panic("!ok")
    }
    v.doStuff()
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the best solution in the general case. However my case is a little bit special, so I think I'll just drop the MyInterface in favor of interface{} and use reflection to force-call MyMethod on it.

Comment: @mzdravkov I'd run benchmarks, because I'd almost bet using my method would be a hell lot faster than using reflection.

Comment: Damn it, you are right. Didn't thought about the performance of reflection. And I'm writing a game engine :D Although, this is not in a performance critical part... I will think about it. Thanks for the notice.